# Drawing boxes error - line too thin

Tags: java

So one of my assignments is that I have to create a box with different colored sides with lines of different thickness. Sounds simple right. That's what I thought, but the issue I'm having is my last line for my box is paper thin when the thickness is set to "40".
I know 40 should be thicker because all the other lines are thicker and are set to lower values than 40. Any suggestions?

```
public class SketchPadDrawing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SketchPad box = new SketchPad();

        box.drawLine(100, 200, 100, 0);
        box.setPenColor("RED");
        box.setPenThickness(10);

        box.drawLine(100, 0, 0, 0);
        box.setPenColor("BLUE");
        box.setPenThickness(20);

        box.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 200);
        box.setPenColor("GREEN");
        box.setPenThickness(30);

        box.drawLine(0, 200, 100, 200);
        box.setPenColor("BLACK");
        box.setPenThickness(40);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post any documentation about the `SketchPad` class? Looks like it is something your professor made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
box.drawLine(0, 200, 100, 200);
box.setPenColor("BLACK");
box.setPenThickness(40);
```

To:

```
box.setPenColor("BLACK");
box.setPenThickness(40);
box.drawLine(0, 200, 100, 200);
```

By the time the last 2 lines of the first code segment have been executed, all drawing is complete.  Therefore they have no effect.

Comment: Well that actually killed my green line but it did correct the black line. I see where you are going with this and changed all line sets to that format (Color, thickness, drawLine) and the result perfect. Great work!

Comment: *"I see where you are going with this.."*  That's the way!  Glad you got it sorted.  :)